String.replace but returning fragments
Here is something that I'd like to achieve:

const symbolRegex = /[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*/g;

export function CodeSymbol(props: {code: string; symbols: SymbolMap}) {
  return (
    <code>
      {props.code.replace(symbolRegex, (symbol): any => {
        const packageName = props.symbols.get(symbol);
        if (packageName) {
          return <a href={`/api/${packageName}/${symbol}`}>{symbol}</a>;
        }
        return <>{symbol}</>;
      })}
    </code>
  );
}

Where SymbolMap is basically a Map<string, string>.
Of course this doesn't work because, the preact fragment is converted to string and I get something like: Observable<[object Object]<any>> from the Observable<HttpEvent<any>> input (HttpEvent is defined in the map, but Observable isn't) .
What would you suggest?

It's a bit hard to understand your exact question, but are you looking for tagged template literals? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals it can return non-strings.

What is symbolRegex? Can you create a self contained example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

@Evert, I need to convert a string to potentially several preact fragments. I'm not sure template literals will help me here.

@MatthieuRiegler it could, but it's probably easier to use .match(), loop through the results, add each fragment to an array and return that.

Here's one way to achieve this by using .split + .map with a regex that has one single capturing group that captures the whole matching part. With a regex like that, every even index in the array will be a non matching substring and every odd one will be a matching substring.
import { render } from 'preact';

const symbolRegex = /([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*)/;

function CodeSymbol(props: {code: string; symbols: SymbolMap}) {
  return (
    <code>
      {props.code.split(symbolRegex).map((symbol, index) => {
        // Every even index is a non-match when the regex has 1 capturing group
        if (index % 2 === 0) return symbol;
        const packageName = props.symbols.get(symbol);
        if (packageName) {
          return <a href={`/api/${packageName}/${symbol}`}>{symbol}</a>;
        }
        return symbol;
      })}
    </code>
  );
}


render(<CodeSymbol code="foo bar" symbols={new Map([["foo", "foopackage"]])} />, document.getElementById('app'));


REPL

You're the man !
